# Encoded Polylines Separator

Tags: google-maps, get, encode, google-polyline

I need to send as GET parameters a list of encoded poly. How can I separate them? Which character could I use to avoid issues?
I need something like this

```
myPage?poly=encoding1;encoding2&other=stuff
```

The polyline encoder which character set uses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm) (emphasys mine):

> The encoding process converts a binary value into a series of character codes for ASCII characters using the familiar base64 encoding scheme: **to ensure proper display of these characters, encoded values are summed with 63 (the ASCII character '?')** before converting them into ASCII.

Thus, you could use any [ASCII character below ASCII 63](http://www.asciitable.com/) (?) to separate your polylines.

Comment: Thanks you. Couldn't see the forest for the trees.